# HTML 5 form validation conditions

Tags: javascript, html, validation

What are the various HTML5 form validation conditions, such as

1. required filed not entered - `valueMissing`,
2. element value doesn't match the type/format - `typeMismatch`,
3. element value doesn't match the pattern - `patternMismatch`
4. value is lower than the provided minimum - `rangeUnderflow`
5. value is higher than the maximum - `rangeOverflow`.

Are there more than these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these sites and used it as my reference:

- http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/13/html5-form-validation.aspx
- http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html
- http://ericleads.com/h5validate/

Credits to the authors.